# Where to control the expireIn JWT

Tags: java, android, json, node.js, jwt

I am building a client-server aplication using android, nodeJS and postgreSQL(sequelize), i already am able to do a simple login and registration, but i want to save sessions so i did this:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
if (JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}") {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Login request body is empty" });
}
if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Missing fields for login" });
}

// search a user to login
User.findOne({ where: { username: req.body.username } }) // searching a user with the same username and password sended in req.body
    .then(function (user) {
        if (user && user.validPassword(req.body.password)) {
            //return res.status(200).json({ message: "loged in!" }); // username and password match


            var payload = { user: user };

            // create a token
            var token = jwt.sign(payload, 'superSecret', {
                expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24
            });


            // return the information including token as JSON
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                token: token
            });

        }
        else {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" }); // if there is no user with specific fields send
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err.stack)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "server issues when trying to login!" }); // server problems
    });
```

});

as you guys can see i return the token to the client when login is sucess, in the client side i save the token on the **SharedPreferences**.

My daubt is that the token has a expiration time, so how can i control the expiration time of the token, should i control it on the server side, or on the client?

any tip is useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using Token method and Session method is not the same. The token is served in the client side so you can send it to the server side and verify if the token has expired or not.

So you can do something like this in your server side to check if the token still available or was expired.

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    /*
        err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
      }
    */
  }
});
```

[Source here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#errors--codes)

For login, you code is correct, but once the user has the token with an expired date, in each request you have to ask if the token is valid and it is not expired. So, first you login the user, and then in each request you ask if the user token is a valid token.

For example:

```
router.get('/posts', function(req, res){
    // here you verify the token
    // if (err)
    // return err, show login to the user
    // else, get all post from database and return the data to the user  
})
```

But is better if you make a function that can be used in every private request you make from the client.

```
function validateToken(token){
    jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
       if (err) {
        /*
            err = {
            name: 'TokenExpiredError',
            message: 'jwt expired',
            expiredAt: 1408621000
          }
        */
      }
}
```

Example using a private request and validating the token before making the request (if validateToken return true, it will go to the function, if not, the request will break on that point):

```
 router.get('/posts', validateToken, function(req, res){
    // get all post from database and return the data to the user
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have a question, is it better to store a session or just the token for a android application?

Comment: I really dont know if you can store a session in android. But im sure that you can store the token in the SharedPreferences because de app is the unique that can access to that preferences, so it is safe to store tokens and easy to use it!. If this answer is the correct, please mark it as that!!

Comment: i mark it as a asnwer, but for example do i need to make a request after login to decode my token that i get from the login?

Comment: You have to create a middleware function on every request you make to the api, and verify if the user has the token and the token is a valid token. If this is true, the request goes to the controller of your backend, if it is not valid, you have to request to the user to login again!

Comment: so after login i need to check that token to get the user, i need to do another request there right?

Comment: I edited the answer but that is another question, you have to learn more about token and user authentification! Good luck!